# USB3 does not work in fresh Ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu, usb-3

I have a new computer with an Asus P8Z68-V LE + Intel  i2500 + 8GB of RAM.

I installed Ubuntu without any issue, but the USB3 (from the motherboard - on the back of the computer) doesn't work.

I plug a USB stick -- nothing, I plug my USB3 external drive -- nothing, when I plug them into the USB2 and everything works perfectly.

Also, I ran all updates and everything is up to date.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd say you're missing the driver for your motherboard's USB3 controller.  What kind of controller is on that motherboard? Which version of Ubuntu?  What drivers, etc. have you tried already?

Comment: i just got the computer with ubuntu 10.10 0 tried 11.10 same result. no idea what kind of controller z68?

Comment: Perhaps check out Asus' web site for info/specs on the controller and maybe even drivers, and update your question with pertinent info.

Comment: they dont have anything i cant find about ubuntu :(

Comment: You probably won't find anything Unbuntu specific. You may find that you have to build some generic Linux drivers up from their source, instead of some easy ready made package. Google your MoBo version with linux as a keyword, hopefully with some searching you'll get there!

Comment: Open a Terminal, and copy/paste the results from the commands `lsusb`, `lspci` and `dmesg |grep -i usb`. Try the same with all your logfiles, you want to look out for everything regarding USB. Does your system recognize the hardware and if so, are there errors?

Comment: I have experienced a number of issues with USB 3.0 and Linux in the past. However, at the moment I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 on an Asus P8 motherboard. (I don't remember the exact motherboard version, but it is probably similar to your P8...). USB 3.0 works out of the box. I didn't have to install any special drivers or do any configuration. It just works. Ubuntu 12.04 seems to handle USB 3.0 better than earlier versions. I had minor USB 3.0 issues with 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a hardware problem. I'm having the same problem on the same type board (Asus p8z77-i) I'm currently building, and I know why; USB 3 won't work on anything but Windows 7 and up (the manual will tell you this in another way as well). It's not the fault of ASUS, it's most motherboards at this point. Look up Linux compatible USB 3 cards because it's worth it (this is true of PCI-E cards for USB 3 functions as well. On New Egg, I found 4 usable cards and 2 were sold out (which should tell you how in demand non-windows USB 3 cards are for us).

But they're less then 40 dollars and USB 3 is 5x faster so it'll save you alot of wait time and frustration. I hope this helps!

Comment: How can it be a hardHow is it a **hardware** problem when you can solve it with other **software** ?

Answer (score 1):

12.04 should be released any day. I would try that before building a custom kernel. I have
an add-in USB card with a NEC controller that works with 11.10. My lspci -nn for that card looks like this

```
02:00.0 USB Controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 03)
```

The driver module is xhci_hcd

```
$ ls -l /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:02\:00.0/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-04-24 17:31 /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/driver -> ../../../../bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd
```

It is not impossible that the only thing that is needed is a mapping from your pci id 
to driver, and the kernel developers are usually quick to add that. Then it might take some 
time to get into the released distributions.